# How I should select my RAM frequency?

Tags: memory, performance, computer-building, components, memory-speed

The first thing is to say that I have searched for a question like this, but I have found only questions about custom or specific components, not a general answer.

So the question is How to choose the best/maximum performance RAM frequency modules? What information should I look for? CPU Max memory support? Motherboard?

The next data is, for only for illustration, so I'm not asking for these components:

- The [AMD Ryzen 5950X](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-9-5950x) have a maximum support of 3200 Mhz of memory speed.
- The [MSI MEG X570 Godlike](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/MEG-X570-GODLIKE/Specification) Motherboard, have a maximum support of 4800 Mhz (or even more with some OC modes).
- The [Corsair VENGEANCE 8 GB DDR4 5000 Mhz C18](https://www.corsair.com/us/en/Categories/Products/Memory/VENGEANCE-LPX/p/CMK16GX4M2Z5000C18), which works at the indicated frequency.

So, in this case. What are the limiting factor? CPU max frequency? The motherboard? If it's the CPU is the limiting factor, what is the purpose of having memories with 5000 Mhz (all the possible processors that can be placed in that motherboard have the same frequency limit). How all of this affects or is affected by the latency of the module (the number after the C), or how this number affects all of this? Is the CPU so low because CPU manufacturers don't want legal issues, but CPUs can achieve more speed?

With this question, I want to be able to choose the best module that the motherboard/cpu configuration can use, but not waste money in a component that will never achieve it's capacities.

Thank you, and sorry for my English.

Comment: The lower common factor is the limiting element. Certain components allow some overclocking functions, and these are often controlled in the BIOS.

Comment: pick your CPU, and then pick a motherboard that will fit it that you like. Then take the max common OC ram frequency between both devices and buy ram that speed. When you build the system, you will likely have to fo into the UEFI and enable overclocking for XMP or whatever. if you get a good motherboard, it will usually make it easy to do.

Comment: also consider buying ram off your motherboards HCL list. provided your CPU supports the frequency, the HCL will usually tell you what speed they tested the ram at, so you can be reasonably sure to get those speeds working. also consider buying all your sticks in a single package. that ensures they were tested together and can reduce the likelihood of getting a stick that doesn't play nicely with the others.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum RAM frequency is dependent upon the memory controller. In older systems the memory controller was in the Northbridge of the motherboard. In modern systems the memory controller is on the CPU package.

You might think that the CPU then dictates what memory you can use, and while that is true the motherboard also must support it. Memory support of motherboards is complex. Most manufacturers provide a Qualified Vendor List (QVL) which lists specific memory modules that are compatible with the motherboard. You can install RAM that is not on the QVL but you can't be sure if it will run at rated speeds.

**It is recommended to choose the best RAM from the QVL of your motherboard.** This advice doesn't account for overclocking. If you are willing to overclock then you don't need to listen to the CPU rated speeds or the motherboard QVL because you can run the RAM faster than either are rated for.

If you install a RAM kit that is rated for higher than the maximum speed listed by your CPU and motherboard it might just work. It might also fail to post with XMP enabled. This is considered a factory overclock. You're on your own to make it work. Nobody will support you because it's outside of the spec of the CPU and MB. You can even run RAM at higher frequencies than it is rated for. That doesn't mean you should. Memory errors lead to system instability.

Try it out. If it doesn't work then return it and buy something off the QVL.